# Comparing text values in Cypress

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cypress

I'm trying to compare two values on a page to make an assertion. I want to capture the value of one text element and compare it with another value on the same page. I'm not sure how to do that in javascript. In Java/selenium this is easy but cypress seems less flexible on this..

Comment: You need to share what you have tried and some code in order for us to help you.

Comment: There's not much to share tbh. I saw the cypress documentation here but it didn't make sense: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/pull/1309/files I have two text elements on the page. I want to make sure the inner text in both of the elements are equal. In cypress, it's not a matter of storing it in a variable and making an assertion. It looked complicated...

Comment: It would be good to share the code because I, myself, is trying to understand the complication. In basic chai concept, it should be like `cy.get(<element>).should('eq', <comparing against another value (maybe stored as a variable)>)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a test comparing two generated strings and if they are not equal after clicking a button:

```js
    it('Test generating new password', () => {
        let password1;
        cy.get('#password').should(($div) => {
            password1 = $div.text();
        });
        cy.get('#generate-button').click();
        cy.get('#password').should(($div) => {
            const password2 = $div.text();
            expect(password1).not.equal(password2);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I used your code because I had the same problem. in my case, I have to compare the same component twice that is synchronised with a clock, then obviously after 1 second it must contain a different text. Do you have any idea why the first variable (in your example password1) is always an empty string? It can take what is written in the second part but not in the first one, and the code is the same, then I cannot understand the problem

Comment: Sorry but without seeing the code it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I solved the problem, I first check that the string exist and then I compare the two strings, in this way it works, thank you anyway

Comment: Glad to hear that :)